# I have tamed an ocelot in 1.14 for PS4, but I can’t get it to follow me

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

I’ve tamed a few ocelots so far, but I can’t get them to follow me back home. Has anyone figured anything out? Google wasn’t any help on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

:)

This is a really weird thing that happened to me as well. I play on PC Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition which is pretty much the Pocket Edition but that shouldn't really matter that much. Anyways, the point is that if your ocelot still looks like an ocelot even after you have "tamed" it - with the little hearts flying around - aka breeding mode, then you had the same issue as me. Basically, for some odd reason, Mojang or Microsoft or whoever controls Minecraft now decided to not allow players to be able to tame Ocelots anymore - at least not for Windows 10 Edition that is. Now the only way that you can tame cats is by finding one near a village. You feed them the same raw fish and all just like you would tame an Ocelot but now you actually have to find an already tamed cat to have it follow you. As you will notice the cats have been given new textures and colors which more than likely implies that this situation was part of the new 1.14 update.

Best regards,

SNOWDOG947

Comment: I have tamed several cats already and I know ocelots don’t become cats anymore. The 1.14 notes say that ocelots are tameable, which I have done, but it won’t follow me afterwards. I am assuming that this may be a glitch, in which case I will have to wait for a fix. If not, then I will have to probably use a Minecart to move my ocelot home and then keep it in a pen. Just checking to see if anyone has found out anything else/different.

Comment: SNOWDOG, do you have any soirces tp back your claims?

Comment: I don't have any sources to back up my claims but play the game for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

When I play it is usually a glitch but sometimes they don’t follow me too. Then i used a lead then they followed me it is best not to fly while doing that.